# Node.js exec: best way of killing a child pipe and all of its children

Tags: bash, node.js

I have a bash command that pipes an audio stream from avconv/ffmpeg to another bash script which must be run with sudo:

`avconv -i http://8273.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WQHTFMAAC_SC -f wav -ac 1 -ar 22050 - | sudo ./pifm -`

The node.js script is used to stop the script from time to time:

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec,
    signal = null;

var signal = exec("avconv -i http://8273.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WQHTFMAAC_SC -f wav -ac 1 -ar 22050 - | sudo ./pifm -")
setTimeout(function() {
    signal.kill('SIGINT')
},10000)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't kill either of the processes in the pipe.

A few further bits of info:

- The resultant PID of the piped process (`console.log(signal.pid)`) doesn't represent the PID's of either process, which I presume is related to the fact that it's a pipe?
- I was able to reliably kill the first child (`avconv`) by adding one to the `signal.pid`, but the PID of the second process (presumably because it's sudo) was not relative to the `signal.pid` and therefore impossible to reliably kill without concocting an elaborate `top | grep` syntax
- I also tried killing the process using the node `process` module:

  ```
  process.kill(this.current.pid,'SIGINT');
  ```

  which didn't work either.
- I'd prefer to avoid using Node to pipe between the two processes, as I'm running this in a low memory environment

I suspect that piped bash processes are unique in some way, but I'm a bit out of my league with the bash end of things!

Comment: I would guess the PID of `signal` would represent the shell which was created in order to run the command. It would make sense that the first process the shell starts would be PID + 1. You'd think killing the shell would kill the processes it started, but I've never tried it with node, and maybe sudo is interfering with your attempt to terminate it. Have you tried profiling using node to pipe the stream in order to verify your memory usage concerns?

Comment: I haven't yet tried using Node for the pipe, mostly because the pipe fodder is perpetual and large (high bandwidth audio) so stuffing that thru Node seemed less ideal than doing it at a lower level.  I'll try it though, and see where I end up!

Comment: In your script, you kill the variable instead of the command it launched.

Comment: Try exec("avconv -i http://8273.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WQHTFMAAC_SC -f wav -ac 1 -ar 22050 - | sudo ./pifm -") whit a PID=$! and then sudo kill -9 $PID

Answer (score 1):

I just remembered I had a similar problem and solved it by using awk to push the command,

```
awk '{system("avconv -i http://8273.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/WQHTFMAAC_SC -f wav -ac 1 -ar 22050 - | sudo ./pifm -")}'
PID=$!


setTimeout(function() {
    sudo kill $PID #(Can try to force it with kill -9 instead)
},10000)
```

This way you really kill the process that owns the command. I'm not sure it will work in your context tough. Farewell friend hope I helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
process.kill(-signal.pid);
```

to terminate the whole process group.